# Present ViewController without Back button

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios

I'm having an annoying problem which takes the best off me :<

I've got 3 view controllers, one to show an advertisement in detail which also has a toolbar. Now what I want is, if the user presses the facebook icon on my toolbar in the first view it has to perform a check. If the check turns out false it needs to go to a 2nd view which shows a login screen. If the user logs in here it has to go to a 3rd screen which shows a simple input + button to update their status.

When the user is at this third screen there should be a button "Back", but this button shouldn't bring them back to View2 but it should bring them back to View1 (the advertisement detail screen).

I figured that I wanted to show the 2nd screen (if check turns false) without pushing it but keeping the NavigationBar + TabBar presented. I added some screenshots to clarify.

**First view**
[image: First view, detailed advertisement information]

**Second view**
[image: If the user clicked on the Facebook icon and the user is not known, this view will be presented. If the user IS known, view 3 will be presented]
I want this view to be presented without using PushViewController but keep the NavigationBar and TabBar.

**Third View**
[image: Third view, if you press Back View1 has to be shown]

I hope this is enough information, hopefully someone can help me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

consider the following view push logic.

```
if (!login) {
    LoginViewController *lvc = [[[LoginViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:lvc];
}
else {
    ThirdViewController *tvc = [[[ThirdViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:tvc];
}
```

It is : create and push the view controller when it is needed.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try some of these solutions out :D you'll hear from me in a bit.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps the most natural thing to do here is to present the login view controller modally. When the user has logged in successfully, the first controller can then push the third view controller onto the navigation stack. This way, the back button will lead directly back to the first view controller, and the user will understand why.

Answer (score 2):

So if we have three UIVIewControllers:

DetailViewController
FacebookLoginViewController
UpdateViewController

We have two viable options:

1) Upon successful login...pop the current LoginViewController and then push the UpdateViewController

```
PopViewController(detailViewController, false);
PushViewController(updateViewController, true);
```

2) Present the login Modally and simply present the UpdateViewController

```
PushModalViewController(loginViewController, true);

//ascertain result of login

if(IsLoggedIn) {
    PushViewController(updateViewController, true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to pop the current view controller (without animation i guess) before pushing the new one. If there is only one view controller in the navigation stack no back button will be shown.

Haven't used Monotouch but i guess something like this:

```
this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(false);
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(newViewController, true);
```

But as Caleb suggests it's probably better figure out a way that fits the normal navigation behaviours instead of hacking around it.

Comment: None of these answers worked for me, sadly. PushModalViewcontroller is not an existing method. What I've tried:

- On the button click push the Login screen (this.NavigationController.PresentModalViewController(login))
- If the login is successfull in the 2nd screen, push: this.NavigationController.PushViewController(statusUpdate)

I'm getting null pointers of the NavigationController. Neither does it work to PopToViewController, getting the error that my viewcontroller doesn't exist :/

Comment: I'm trying to pop the login screen by doing: this.NavigationController.PopViewControllerAnimated(true)
this.NavigationController.PushViewController(updateStatus, true)
but I am getting null pointer in the navigation controller for some reason